# Query to fetch last value in a column in derby database table

Tags: java, sql, derby, javadb

I want to fetch last value in a column in a row in a derby db table. Can someone help me?

Comment: "Last" depending on what? Rows in a relational database are ***not*** sorted. So you will have to use some kind of `order by` criteria. Please supply us with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Say for example, What you can see below is the data in the table in derby db.

  firstcol   secondcol Thirdcol
   1    33            33
   2    45            55
   3    78            79


I want to fetch last value in the ‘secondcol’ column. The output should be 78.

For this desired output, how can I query it from derby database table.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the data properly. Why is 78 the "last" value, if there is a *79*?

Comment: i will try to give u in a better format.

Comment: Sorry,I m not able to format the sample data table,whatever I do the format changes.

 So ill describe you.
Imagine a table which has ‘secondcol’ as a column.  The values in the column are 33,45,78.

 I want to fetch last value in the ‘secondcol’ column. The output should be 78.

For this desired output, how can I query it from derby database table.

Comment: select * from mytable where secondcol = (select max(secondcol) from mytable)

Comment: I want the most recently inserted value in the column irrespective of min or max in the column value. In sql, we can use last(column_name) from table_name, which would fetch the last inserted value in the column.  If I wish to get the output in similar way in derby what can i use?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.rawImport
WHERE number= ( select max(number)
                    from dbo.rawImport)
```

Comment: Damn, let me edit it. Wrote it quickly yesterday, would something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you are trying to get last id (numeric value)

```
SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

thats it.

And if you want to get whole data of last row then call `getRowCount()` method and select the record at that reference. check out code example.
**getRowCount() method:**

```
public int getRowCount(String tableName) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            res = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
            while (res.next()) {
                count = res.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table not found record getting");
        }
        return count;
    }
```

It will return an int value so use it as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = getRowCount(TABLE_NAME);
```

And the result is your last record.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
order by id DESK OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```